# Checkbox click overriding table row click

Tags: javascript, html

I have checkbox inside HTML table and I set onclick event on the HTML table row.

When I click the table row, it will fire a function on my script

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="sayHello('Hello World');">
         <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
         <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is when I click a checkbox inside that row, it also will fire the row's onclick event

How to prevent that?

Comment: @Vohuman, yes I know about that. Technically, I can move the onclick event to the <td> tag, but I think it's redudant if I set the event on each <td>. So I wanna see whether there's another options or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("tr input");

for (var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr onclick="alert('Hello World');">
         <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
         <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Stop the event from propagating to the table:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("tr input");

for (var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply add `onclick` event of checkbox to call `event.stopPropagation()`

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" />
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Good to read one is 
http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5jnfzy7o/

```
var c=document.getElementById('something')
c.addEventListener('click', function(){
event.stopPropagation(); //Stops event from bubbling up the DOM Tree
});
function sayHello(str){
  alert(str);
}
```

For HTML :

```
<table>
<tr onclick="sayHello('Hello World');">
     <td><input type="checkbox" id="something"/></td>
     <td>Column 1</td>
     <td>Column 2</td>
     <td>Column 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just faced with event bubbling :)

You have to stop the propagation using [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) event's method. See an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the propagation of the click event.

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation()
})
```

You can start from the MDN documentation about [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) and read on event flow to understand more about this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
sayHello = function(whatToSay)
{
   alert(whatToSay);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr onclick="sayHello('Hello World');">
         <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" /></td>
         <td>Column 1</td>
         <td>Column 2</td>
         <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```